# How to "correctly" reduce downtime with Cloud Foundry deployments?

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry, downtime, blue-green-deployment

I am using Blue-Green deployment in order to reduce deployment downtime of a Cloud Foundry application (NodeJS).
I am using BlueGreenDeploy plugin for the Cloud Foundry Command Line Interface (cf CLI) (https://github.com/bluemixgaragelondon/cf-blue-green-deploy) and my app is running several processes for single instance employing PM2 Cluster Mode.

Everything is working fine but I want to know if there are some "Best Practices" or things I am not doing correctly.

For example: does it help if I manually scale-down my application to only 1 instance before to push my application? App instances are specified in the manifest file so it is CF itself that manages the scale up process.

Thanks in advance to everyone who will help me.

Comment: >does it help if I manually scale-down my application to only 1 instance before to push my application? No

Comment: Are you seeing any specific problems or encountering any challenges with what you're doing? If not, then I would rest easy.

Comment: Hi Daniel and thank you very much for your response. I have also another question, maybe I will post a separate question for this but probably you can help me. I am using Cloud Foundry on IBM and I am experimenting some longtail latency: a very small portion of the requests takes much longer than the average response time. I read that with GO KA enabled I can reduce this. My question is: is there a way I can figure out if it is enabled? I think I don't have access to the GoRouter configuration.

Comment: Sounds like something IBM support would need to confirm.

Comment: Thank you Daniel!